# How to expand a matrix in Eigen?

Tags: matrix, eigen, matrix-multiplication

Suppose that I have a matrix `Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 3>` whose entries are

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

How can I expand it to

```
1 2 3 0
4 5 6 0
7 8 9 0
0 0 0 1
```

I need this to multiply 3D affine/projective transformations (4 by 4, under the type Eigen::Transform) with 3D rotation matrices (3 by 3).

Comment: Is stackoverflow correct platform? How about http://math.stackexchange.com ?

Answer (score 5):

You want [conservativeResize](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1PlainObjectBase.html#a4ac24a195e3e35ce2d8946cee5873e51):

```
Eigen::MatrixXf mat;
mat.resize(3,3);
mat << 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9;
std::cout << mat << "\n\n";
mat.conservativeResize(4,4);
mat.col(3).setZero();
mat.row(3).setZero();
mat(3, 3) = 1;
std::cout << mat << "\n\n";
```

Comment: Is there a static version?

Comment: A static version of what?

Comment: @HenricusV. see https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialBlockOperations.html, some operations have static versions, but not these ones.